# docker-compose version 3 doesn't recognize runtime

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I met the following issue that compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  minkowski:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileGPU
    volumes:
      - "../:/app:rw"
      - "${DATA_PATH}:/app/data:rw"
    working_dir: /app
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    network_mode: "host"
    runtime: nvidia
```

results in

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker/compose-gpu.yaml' is invalid because:
services.minkowski.build contains unsupported option: 'runtime'
```

I have docker version 20.10.21 and docker-compose 1.25.0. Do you have any idea why that happens?

I tried use different versions. Running

```
sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi
```

works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by installing the newer `docker compose`. With `docker compose` 2.x it works just fine, without further changes

Answer (score 0):

The `runtime:` option isn't supported in [Compose file version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/); it is only in [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#runtime).  More broadly, current versions of Compose support both Compose file versions 2 and 3, and it's okay to use either.  Version 3's options are more oriented towards the Swarm orchestrator and for some single-host-specific options like this you need to use version 2.

```yaml
version: '2.4' # not 3.x
services:
  ...:
    runtime: nvidia
```

The newer Compose Specification [also supports `runtime:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#runtime) but support for this is inconsistent across Compose versions.  The Compose 1.25.0 you mention will not support it.  That doesn't suggest specific values for [`version:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-top-level-element), and I might label a file as `version: '4.0'` if you're using Compose Specification specific functionality.